# Unable to run Aerospike python client on MAC with M1 chip

Tags: python, python-3.x, aerospike

Hi I am trying to setup my local dev environment. I have installed aerospike==5.0.0. But I am unable to import it due to x86_64 architecture not being supported.

```
In [1]: import aerospike
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d60dd2d8373f> in <module>
----> 1 import aerospike

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mudit/.virtualenvs/payments/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aerospike.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/mudit/.virtualenvs/payments/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aerospike.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/aerospike.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/aerospike.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

If I downgrade the python version to 3.7 I am unable to install aerospike getting following error:

```
pip install aerospike==5.0.0

Collecting aerospike==5.0.0
  Using cached aerospike-5.0.0.tar.gz (182 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/mudit/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/envs/myenv/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/d3/p7j4w0dx1d56h05_2pwpf4q80000gp/T/pip-install-c0ra2cak/aerospike/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/d3/p7j4w0dx1d56h05_2pwpf4q80000gp/T/pip-install-c0ra2cak/aerospike/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/d3/p7j4w0dx1d56h05_2pwpf4q80000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-zqg4d0y6
         cwd: /private/var/folders/d3/p7j4w0dx1d56h05_2pwpf4q80000gp/T/pip-install-c0ra2cak/aerospike/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/mudit/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution
      File "/Users/mudit/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
        from setuptools import windows_support
      File "/Users/mudit/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/Users/mudit/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have even tried running my project on docker but still the aerospike installation is failing.

```
12 4.293     info: Executing ./scripts/aerospike-client-c.sh
#12 4.293     info: downloading 'https://artifacts.aerospike.com/aerospike-client-c/5.2.0/aerospike-client-c-devel-5.2.0.debian11.x86_64.deb' to '/tmp/pip-install-ydkcep01/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/package/aerospike-client-c-devel-5.2.0.debian11.x86_64.deb'
#12 4.293       % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#12 4.293                                      Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100  2163  100  2163    0     0   3814      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3814
#12 4.293     info: extracting files from 'aerospike-client-c-devel-5.2.0.debian11.x86_64.deb'
#12 4.293     dpkg-deb: error: 'aerospike-client-c-devel-5.2.0.debian11.x86_64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
#12 4.293
#12 4.293     CHECK
#12 4.293        [✗] /tmp/pip-install-ydkcep01/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/package/usr/lib/libaerospike.a
#12 4.293        [✗] /tmp/pip-install-ydkcep01/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/package/usr/include/aerospike/aerospike.h
#12 4.293
#12 4.293     error: scripts/aerospike-client-c.sh 1
```

Can Somebody pls suggest a way to successfully import aerospike python client on MacOs Monterey with M1 chip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use KubeLab you can run Intel (x86_64, amd64) Docker images on Apple M1 processors. https://github.com/aerospike-community/docker-amd64-mac-m1

There are instructions for how to run the Aerospike server image with this.