# Unable to install Aerospike pip package | Macbook M1 chip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, apple-m1, aerospike

I am trying to install aerospike in my virtualenv by using below command

```
pip install aerospike==5.0.0
```

but it is unable to install. It is throwing below error

```
Collecting aerospike==5.0.0
  Using cached aerospike-5.0.0.tar.gz (182 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: aerospike
  Building wheel for aerospike (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [150 lines of output]
      info: Executing ./scripts/aerospike-client-c.sh

# ... very long output ... #   
      
      ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib'
      ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
      ld: library not found for -lssl
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> aerospike

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have tried to install wheel and then install this package but it's not working.
I have also tried by installing rosetta2 on mac but it didn't work.

Also, if it requires whole output do let me know where I can share that publish the link here in my question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70169208/unable-to-run-aerospike-python-client-on-mac-with-m1-chip

Comment: Indeed... https://github.com/aerospike-community/docker-amd64-mac-m1